# Specify visual studio version in nar-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-nar-plugin

I have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed.  Is there a way to specify which version of visual studio to use?  Also, what if I want to generate NARs for multiple versions of Visual Studio, can the NAR plugin handle this?

Ideally, the end product would be something like:

```
some-shared-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-amd64-Windows-msvc-2012-shared.nar 
some-shared-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-amd64-Windows-msvc-2010-shared.nar
...
```

Or at least having some way of telling what version of visual studio was used to produce a NAR.  Is this possible with the nar-maven-plugin?